# Where to locate mongoDB and data folder?

Tags: mongodb

I downloaded and installed mongoDB on windows , it ran fine on C: partition using data folder at C:\data.
then I moved my mongoDB folder to D: partirion.
and now need to change my data folder too.
Please help me locating data folder, mongoDB is actually a bunch of folders inside each other so at the top level is mongoDB -> server -> 3.2 -> bin -> .....all files ....
even though i added the path of \bin folder to my system variables I often get this error on terminal :

```
$ mongod --dbpath=data
2016-09-03T16:58:41.710+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=9680 port=27017 dbpath=data 64-bit host=Maryam
2016-09-03T16:58:41.711+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2016-09-03T16:58:41.711+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.9
2016-09-03T16:58:41.712+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 22ec9e93b40c85fc7cae7d56e7d6a02fd811088c
2016-09-03T16:58:41.712+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
2016-09-03T16:58:41.712+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-09-03T16:58:41.712+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-09-03T16:58:41.712+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-09-03T16:58:41.712+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2016-09-03T16:58:41.712+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-09-03T16:58:41.712+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-09-03T16:58:41.712+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "data" } }
2016-09-03T16:58:41.713+0100 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:10048 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2016-09-03T16:58:41.713+0100 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2016-09-03T16:58:41.714+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

and here is my port on netstat:
[image: port]
so where can i add my data/db , and on which folder shall i run my command mongod --dbpath=data ? please help. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: The error says the `bind` failed. Did you check whether there is an existing instance is already running or the port is not consumed?

Comment: use `netstat` command to check if the port is used by some other process.

Comment: i have a copy of data/db on C: still and when i run mongo it says connecting to test

Comment: just to clearify ,, i can run mongo using the old data on C:\

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that putting the data/db next to mongoDB at the same level is working fine. 
although that mongoDB folder still having chain of folders like i mentioned above in the question but puttin data at the same level of the parent folder (mongoDB) works fine.

here is a screenshot of my folder:
[image: data folder]